# Augmented Reality application showing `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception

Tags: android, android-emulator, vuforia

I'm using the ImageTargets example, and for whatever reason, I'm getting a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I try to call the ImageTargets  library.

Any ideas why? Do I have to set my path somewhere?

I followed the guide at [this link](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-1-setting-development-environment-android-sdk). I installed everything fine. After setting vuforia path I imported `ImageTargets` sample application but when I run that application I am getting `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception`, I don't know what I did wrong please any one suggest me thank you...

**below is my logcat**

```
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:      
Nativemethod not found:     
com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.ImageTargets.getOpenGlEsVersionNative:()I
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at  com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.ImageTargets.getOpenGlEsVersionNative(Native Method)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.ImageTargets.getInitializationFlags(ImageTargets.java:384)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.ImageTargets.onCreate(ImageTargets.java:355)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-06 07:11:21.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you compiled the NDK library that comes along with the ImageTargets project?

Comment: no.how to do same i follwed that link.what i have to please help me

Comment: It may be easier if you follow the third step in the same setup tutorial you're referring to.

Comment: ;C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ ;C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\;C:\cygwin\bin\;C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r8\ in environment vaeribles i set path like this

Comment: and i installed vouforia sdk,after that i set path in eclips preferences-java-build-calss pathvariable in that  i folder  C:\Development\Android\vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31

Comment: in side vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31/samples not projects are there. so i just downloded all samples and i copied all those samples apps in samples folder..... and i imported one sample app ImageTarget and i run that sample.but i am facing above error

Comment: yes i follwed i did same.but where i did wrong i didnt get any idea. if u didnt get  what said clearly i ll tel u again also.if u get any idea please help me

Answer (score 0):

defaultConfig {
    ...

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
}
```

}
You need to add this filters(abiFilters) to your app module’s build.gradle files. So when your device try to run your app, it will check gradle file and understands that it should not generate any folder and use existing native library resources. Boom. Almost solved. But still there is one more thing.

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Add this line to your gradle.properties to use deprecated Ndk.

for more detail check the link 
https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d